# Number being converted to currency

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm working on a wordpress website that uses gravityforms.
One of the fields in a form is a radio button that has only 1 option.
The value of the field is as follows: `donderdag 5 juni 2014 | 100`.

When reading the email it shows as `donderdag 5 juni 2014 (€ 100,00)`.
Is this because of the `|` sign?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is due to the pipe character, Gravity Forms uses that to separate the choice label from the choice price. You'll need to use a different character.

Comment: I tried replacing it with a capitol i `I` but then I don't see the 100 at all. Same goes for a slash `/`. EDIT: This might be due to caching. I'm gonna test a bit more.